# Java synchronization and double checking issue

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package remotedebug;


public abstract class AppSM extends JDynamicEventProcessor implements SyncCallbackListener
{
    public static final String IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS";

    protected EventManager eventMgr;
    protected Synchronizer syncRef = null;
    protected static AppSM _self = null;
    protected AppSMHandler _appHandler = null;
    protected SMServiceHandler _serviceHandlerRef = null;
    protected AppSP _scriptProcessor = null;

    /**
    *  \brief This variable is used for the Trace Logger.
    */
    private static com.tracelibrary.TraceLogger _trace;



    private InfoHolder _stateInfoHolder;

    private ResultInfo _resultInfo;

    public static AppSM getInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            if( _self == null)
            {


                _trace = new com.tracelibrary.TraceLogger();
                _trace.TRACE_LOGGER("AppSM");
                _trace.LOG_TRACE("Creating instance");
                 synchronized(AppSM.class){ 
                if( _self == null){
                _self = new AppGen("App" ,"stb");
                _self.Processor(System.getProperty("DIR"));
                 }
                 }
                return _self;
            }
            else
            {
                _trace.LOG_TRACE("returning instance");
                return _self;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

1. I am running coverity server for static code analysis but I am
   getting error  according to coverity

   > Check of thread-shared field evades lock acquisition" erro  "LOCK_EVASION", and categories "Data race undermines locking"

   I am not sure why is this issue is occurring?
2. My question is why this issue is occurring even if I am using static variable.
3. Would using volatile help me in this situation?

4.why coverity is giving **correlated_field: The modification of _trace can race with the unguarded check of _self.**  even my _trace is static if I will make my _trace to final my issue will solve or not ??

```
4.a) what is unguarded check of _self  
4.b)what is correlated_field
```

5 what is this coverity reports
 **thread1_modifies_field: Thread1 modifies the static field _self. This modification can be re-ordered with other correlated field assignments within this critical section at runtime**

```
5.a)what is re-ordered   
5.b)what is correlated field
```

### For better understanding, please see what are information given by coverity server

```
1. thread1_checks_field: Thread1 uses the value read from static field _self in the condition AppSM._self == null. It sees that the condition is true.

CID 212049 (#1 of 5): Check of thread-shared field evades lock acquisition (LOCK_EVASION)

5. thread2_checks_field_early: Thread2 checks _self, reading it after Thread1 assigns to _self but before some of the correlated field assignments can occur. It sees the condition AppSM._self == null as being false. It continues on before the critical section has completed, and can read data changed by that critical section while it is in an inconsistent state.
    Remove this outer, unlocked check of _self.
                         if( _self == null)
                         {


    6. correlated_field: The modification of _trace can race with the unguarded check of _self.
                               _trace = new com.tracelibrary.TraceLogger();
                              _trace.TRACE_LOGGER("AppSM");
                              _trace.LOG_TRACE("Creating instance");
    2. thread1_acquires_lock: Thread1 acquires lock ViewerAppSM.class.
                                 synchronized(AppSM.class){ 
    3. thread1_double_checks_field: Thread1 double checks the static field _self in the condition com.AppSM._self == null.
                                 if( _self == null){
    4. thread1_modifies_field: Thread1 modifies the static field _self. This modification can be re-ordered with other correlated field assignments within this critical section at runtime. Thus, checking the value of _self is not an adequate test that the critical section has completed unless the guarding lock is held while checking. If _self is assigned a newly constructed value, note that the JVM is allowed to reorder the assignment of the new reference to _self before any field assignments that may occur in the constructor. Control is switched to Thread2.
```

Comment: Double-check locking doesn't work in Java: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Double-check locking works for a long time with volatile

Comment: @MauricePerry Double-checked locking has worked in Java since at least 1.5.

Comment: Oh! that's cool! I'm gonna put them everywhere

Comment: Please give proper solution why the issue is coming what could be the proper fix.I had already spent time on google, visited many blogs

Comment: A proper solution would be to get rid of this double-check locking and instanciate your singleton as suggested by @yeppe's second link.